# Asp.Net How to share the data stored in cache across applications running in same application pool

Tags: iis, memory, share

Right now I am storing some data in memory using ObjectCache in web api. But I need this data to be accessed by another web api running in the same application pool. Please advise. I am using IIS 8.5.

Comment: Add the code what you have tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to avoid that complex things, since you will have too much pain sharing memory across the pool/memory of differents apps.

Is not possible that you create a webservice as an cache for the n-applications you want to share? 
In that webservice you could use anything you think fits best for storing in memory

```
[HttpGet("set/{keyname}/{data}")]
public IActionResult SetData(string keyname,string data)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(keyname, data);
    return Ok("session data set");
}

[HttpGet("get")]
public IActionResult GetData(string keyname)
{
    var sessionData = HttpContext.Session.GetString(keyname);
    return Ok(sessionData);
}
```

Comment: Thanka for the response. I am.also trying the same. One service will store data in memory which can be accessed by all the other applications in the same app pool. Please let me know how to do.

Comment: Please check  as the answer, I will edit it to show you how